# Unexpected behavior from $_POST string variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, post

I was working on a simple accent stripping function on PHP

```
$your_data = $_POST["input"];

function stripchar($str) {
                  $char = array(
                      'a'=>'á|à|ặ|â',

                    );

                foreach($char as $stripped_char => $original_char){
                        $str = preg_replace("/($original_char)/i", $stripped_char, $str);
            }
            return $str;
            }

echo stripchar($your_data);
```

It worked well if I try to echo accented characters (á à ặ â), of which it would return the intended characters (a a a a).

However, when I put into use - taking a string variable from $string = $_POST["input"] from the html file, inputted by the user, the function did not change the accented characters at all.

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="inputbox">
        <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
                <textarea type="text" name="input" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Strip" class="button_form">
        </form> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still quite confused. Tried var_dump the $string variable and it showed up as string variable. I also tested another function that takes accented string in the script again, and it still worked. But not from the string from the input field!

Comment: It could be something about html/server encoding, did you check the same encoding along html / server / php script ?

Comment: Is this code erring or only with the POST? You don't need the preg_replace, str_replace should work...or is `$str` the POST?

Comment: please don't arbitrarily remove accents because your code cant Handel them properly.

Comment: @ontanaza How can I check that? As for the file itself, I made sure they are all utf-8 encoding file. But I'm not sure about the string that the html file send to the php file.

Comment: @chris85 It didn't work only with the $str var from POST

Comment: What is the input you are passing it?

Comment: @chris85 accented characters, eg "á à ặ â"

Comment: That works fine so it must be your form not sending it as UTF8. Look at the request and see what the content-type is sending as in the response header.

Comment: Just an additional note: The textarea element doesn't need the attribute `type="text"`.

Comment: @chris85: I check the request headers and got this: 

`Host: localhost Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 4145 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 Origin: http://localhost User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Referer: http://localhost/dias/home.html Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,vi;q=0.6 Cookie: ` 


I still have no clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer for it - turns out the problem lies not in the server side script, but from the client side - specifically from my html file. The html form just send broken accented strings, thus my php script couldn't handle the string as expected at all.

So I just add this line `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the html file and everything works now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function stripAccents($stripAccents){
  return strtr($stripAccents,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
}
```